# Query is taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization

we have over 100 million records in our SQL database, we we are trying to process them. We had a script prepared by vendor, but it is taking too long. I am not a programmer, but this looks like a very inefficient way to do this. Can someone please help?

I programmed just a little bit in ACCESS, but it looks like nested CONVERT and all those operations are killing the system. We ran it for 8 hours and it did not even process 1% of all the records.

```
Create view Base_List as
SELECT
  Archive.dbo.Inum_location.inum,
  Archive.dbo.Media.name as media_name,
  Archive.dbo.Media.physical_device,
  Archive.dbo.Container.path,
  Archive.dbo.Container.length,
  CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.p1_value,
  CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.p2_value,
  CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.p3_value,
  CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.contact_id
FROM
          CentralContact.dbo.Sessions INNER JOIN
          Archive.dbo.Inum_location INNER JOIN
          Archive.dbo.Container ON Inum_location.container_id = Container.container_id ON CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varchar,
          CentralContact.dbo.Sessions.audio_module_no) + RIGHT('000000000' + CONVERT(varchar, CentralContact.dbo.Sessions.audio_ch_no), 9))
          = Inum_location.inum INNER JOIN
          CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd ON CentralContact.dbo.Sessions.dbs_id = CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.dbs_id AND
          CentralContact.dbo.Sessions.sid = CentralContact.dbo.Sessions_pd.sid     INNER JOIN
              Archive.dbo.Media ON Inum_location.media_id = Media.media_id;

SELECT
  A1_CAP0_UCS.*,
  Base_List.*
FROM
  A2_CAP0_UCS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Base_List ON
  A2_CAP0_UCS.[Column 3] = Base_List.p1_value;
```

Comment: Add table definitions, indexes etc.

Comment: Could you add a column to CentralContact.dbo.Sessions to store the calculations result and add a trigger to update the column on INSERT or UPDATE. Then you can add an index for the column?

Comment: This is for SQL Server? Tag DBMS used please...

Comment: After I updated the index, it ran much faster, but now, I am really curious if this was the best way to write it. Too many inner joins and nested CONVERTS.

Comment: As long as the joins can use effective indices i see no proplem there - the join on Convert is not optimal as it is very bad for index usage. Does not seem like a good database design if you have to do a join on a convert like that.

Comment: Send it back to the vendor and require thorough review for performance. You can't just drop in our lap and expect to do the work that should have been done by the vendor.